# How to know what are all the MediaWiki web pages without categories?

Tags: mediawiki

In some large wikis one might find some rare web pages that don't have categories (for example, when these pages were created, the creator forgot to add a category).

How to know what are all the MediaWiki web pages **without** categories?

I didn't find such a list web-page at `special:special_pages` (translated from Hebrew).

Comment: Seems like there's a few ways you could do this: the [categorylinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table) stores the page.page_id as `cl_from` and the category as `cl_to`. Easiest way is probably to do an outer JOIN, with a test for `WHERE cl_to is null`. {Looks like an [SQL course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/intro-sql) might be handy!}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's at `Special:UncategorizedPages`. There are also a couple other `Special:Uncategorized*` pages for other namespaces (images, categories etc).

Comment: Oh, there was a language confusion there. In Hebrew one can say "ללא" and "חסרי", both mean without; the first word used for some pages but the second word used for that page and thus I found it this time in the list. It should be noted I couldn't address that page from URL in English sadly; I wish the URLs were all English even in different language Wikis. Thanks.

Comment: English URLs do work on every wiki.